# Write Batchfile output to VTS

Tags: batch-file, performance-testing, loadrunner

A Batch file is executed and it gives few parameters as output.I need to write those output parameters in virtual table server (VTS), as i need to pass them to my LR Script.
Output of Batch file

```
    USING API KEY : Android
Base URL = /user/authorization
HEADERS :
accessKey = 45k907its35dooeo182dm0guy8k0dv8o
signature = Tdo0ZBfZazTvYd8UwmHT+haq2vM=
timestamp = 1455397355435enter
```

The major concern is, the output of batch-file is valid only for few minutes(HMACSHA1), i cant wait to copy it in csv file and then upload it in VTS. Any ideas how I can directly write it on VTS. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having your batch automatically output the CSV and then also automatically upload it to VTS.  Otherwise, the API in use is a set of LoadRunner libraries.

An alternate path that I often use is with RabbitMQ.  With the management plugin there is an HTTP interface available that you could push data with CURL and then pull it using a standard HTTP call from within your virtual user.   I use Rabbit MQ for it's open back end to use stuff outside of a LoadRunner virtual user to seed a queue and also because the HTTP interface is simpler than the VTS API set.

Comment: Hello James,Thanks for looking into it.Yes I'm able to automate the output to CSV, but not sure how to automatically upload to VTS.could you please help on that.

Comment: use MDRV to kick off a single virtual user with the VTS functions to load the data into VTS

http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/The-New-Virtual-Table-Server-VTS-in-LoadRunner-11-52/ba-p/6069435#.V50eVfkrJhE